# Use of Streams/Sinks in a simple BLoC Example

Tags: flutter, bloc

I'm trying to understand a simple BLoC example for an app that increments/decrements a counter based on buttons (i.e., the default Flutter app, with an added button for decrementing counter).

I'm having trouble understanding why we need to manage three streams/sinks in class `CounterBloc`:

1. `StreamSink<int> get _inCounter => _counterStateController.sink;`
2. `Stream<int> get counter => _counterStateController.stream;`
3. `Sink<CounterEvent> get counterEventSink => _counterEventController.sink;`

In particular, why do we need a separate variables for `_inCounter` and `counter`?

Full code below:

`counter_event.dart`:

```
class IncrementEvent extends CounterEvent {}

class DecrementEvent extends CounterEvent {}
```

---

`counter_bloc.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter_bloc/counter_event.dart';

class CounterBloc {
  int _counter = 0;

  final _counterStateController = StreamController<int>();
  StreamSink<int> get _inCounter => _counterStateController.sink;
  Stream<int> get counter => _counterStateController.stream;

  final _counterEventController = StreamController<CounterEvent>();
  Sink<CounterEvent> get counterEventSink => _counterEventController.sink;

  CounterBloc() {
    _counterEventController.stream.listen(_mapEventToState);
  }

  _mapEventToState(CounterEvent event) {
    if (event is IncrementEvent)
      _counter++;
    else
      _counter--;

    _inCounter.add(_counter);
  }

  void dispose() {
    _counterStateController.close();
    _counterEventController.close();
  }
}
```

---

Relevant excerpt of `main.dart`:

````
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _bloc = CounterBloc();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: _bloc.counter,
          initialData: 0,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            return Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                ),
                Text(
                  '${snapshot.data}',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First you need to understand that we're using `StreamController`, which is basically like a pipe. You put a value using `sink` and you get that value at the other end using `stream`.**

We're declaring `_counterStateController` as `StreamController` for controlling `_counter` value. Whatever value you put through `_inCounter`, you'll get that value using the stream `counter`

```
  final _counterStateController = StreamController<int>();
  StreamSink<int> get _inCounter => _counterStateController.sink;
  Stream<int> get counter => _counterStateController.stream;
```

The other sink `counterEventSink` is a sink for `_counterEventController` StreamController, which you'll use for controller `CounterEvent`, IncrementEvent or DecrementEvent.

```
  final _counterEventController = StreamController<CounterEvent>();
  Sink<CounterEvent> get counterEventSink => _counterEventController.sink;
```

Whatever value you put the sink `_counterEventController` which is `counterEventSink`, you'll get that value through it's stream which we'll listen to when we'll create out `CounterBloc` object.

```
 CounterBloc() {
    _counterEventController.stream.listen(_mapEventToState); //listening to the CounterEvent Stream
  }
```

And here we're passing `_mapEventToState` function as a callback. This function will be called whenever you put any value to the `counterEventSink`.

In the `_mapEventToState`, we're simply checking which type of event is passed and then we're adding that value to the `_inCounter` which is stream of `_counterStateController`. So anything you add to `_inCounter` will be received through `counter`.

```
_mapEventToState(CounterEvent event) {
    if (event is IncrementEvent)
      _counter++;
    else
      _counter--;

    _inCounter.add(_counter);
  }
```